# Access TextBox (with ClientIDRowSuffix in ControlID) within ListView from code-behind during page creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview

I have a page with a ListView:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="lvContacts" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Predictable" ClientIDRowSuffix="ContactID">
      <LayoutTemplate>
        <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="contactContainer">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text="Last Name"></asp:TextBox>
          <!-- other elements removed for clarity -->
        </div>
      </ItemTemplate>      
    </asp:ListView>
```

The datasource of this ListView is set during Page_Load.

This works fine and when I check the HTML of the generated page, the ContactIDs (14003 in this case) are added correctly at the end of the IDs of the textboxes:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$lvContacts$ctrl0$txtFirstName" type="text" value="First Name" id="MainContent_lvContacts_txtFirstName_14003" />
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$lvContacts$ctrl0$txtLastName" type="text" value="Last Name" id="MainContent_lvContacts_txtLastName_14003" />
```

However I would like to manipulate the textboxes in code-behind (C#) before the page gets sent to the browser.

I have tried

```
FindControl("txtLastName_14003");
FindControl("lvContacts_txtLastName_14003");
FindControl("MainContent_lvContacts_txtLastName_14003");
```

and also the recursive variant

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string controlID)
{
  if (rootControl.ID == controlID) return rootControl;

  foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
  {
    Control controlToReturn = FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID);
    if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn;
  }
  return null;
}
```

but none of the above returns the control I'm searching for.

When I loop through all the controls in my page, the textbox IDs are displayed without the ClientIDRowSuffix, so:

```
lvContacts
  ctrl0
    txtFirstName
    txtLastName
  ctrl1
    txtFirstName
    txtLastName
  ctrl2
    txtFirstName
    txtLastName
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to access the controls within the ListView during page creation by searching on their ID incl. ClientIDRowSuffix? 
If so, I would love to get an example!

If not, are there other ways to manipulate these textboxes based on the ContactID before the page gets sent to the browser?

Comment: _"are added correctly at the end of the IDs"_ What has added the contact id to the end? That's not the default behaviour if the ID is `txtFirstName`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The ContactID has been added automatically by the ListView-setting 'ClientIDRowSuffix="ContactID"' In my example, the ContactID is 14003 and the ID of the textbox is automatically set to 'MainContent_lvContacts_txtFirstName_14003'. Which I expected, but please explain to me what should have been the default. And how to access this textbox from code-behind during page creation.